# Lie group action with no slice

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $x\in M$, $M$ - finite dimensional smooth manifold. Is there an example of a finite dimensional Lie group action on $M$ with no slice at $x$?

Comment: Please read http://mathoverflow.net/howtoask and revise this question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that if a free action of G on M has a slice S at a point x then the natural map of G x S into M given by (g,s) maps to gs would be a diffeomorphism onto a tubular neighborhood of the orbit Gx. So for a counterexample take the action of the real line on the 2-torus given by a 1-parameter subgroup with irrational slope acting by translation.

Comment: After thinking about my answer a bit I realized that an even simpler example is the action of the group Z of integers on the circle generated by rotation through an irrational angle.

Comment: The action of $\mathbb{R}$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by $(x,y)\mapsto (x,y+ax)$ is also a classic.  The y-axis is fixed, but has no slice.

Comment: @Yves Cormulier  I don't think that's so Yves. If it were then even a compact group action wouldn't have a slice at an isolated fixed point p, whereas in fact an invariant neighborhood of p is a slice at p in that case.

Comment: @Dick You're right, I erased by previous comment. I had a misconception of the notion, which is definitely global.